# Difference between Semigroup and SemigroupK

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In cats there are 2 semigroup types classes: `Semigroup` and `SemigroupK` with the latter working on type constructors.
I fail to see the advantages of the latter over the former. If I look at the list instances they are providing `Monoid` (although there is a `MonoidK`), whereas `NonEmptyList` is providing a `SemigroupK`. Note that `NonEmptyList` is also providing a `Semigroup` via the following method:

```
implicit def catsDataSemigroupForNonEmptyList[A]: Semigroup[NonEmptyList[A]] =
  SemigroupK[NonEmptyList].algebra[A]
```

Why the discrepancy?

Then it seems that most semigroup operations are only available on `Semigroup` and not `SemigroupK` (there's `reduceK` in `Reducible` but that's the only one I saw, and it delegates to `reduce` which works on `Semigroup`).

So, given a type `T[_]`, what would you gain by having both a `SemigroupK[T]` *and* a `Semigroup[T[A]] for some A`?

**Edit**

There's now an issue to remove MonoidK and SemigroupK: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1932

Comment: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/SemigroupK.html You may want take a look at this

Comment: From what I can tell cats provides a `SemigroupK` for both `List` and `NonEmptyList` in `0.8`. If you take a look at `catsStdInstancesForList` the `MonadCombine` in there extends a `SemigroupK`.

Comment: @jilen I read this but it's not really answering my question

Comment: @DenisRosca I saw that on cats 0.7.2, so it's possible that it got added in a later release, which still makes me wonder what you're gaining by having both type classes?

Comment: For future reference: the Cats documentation for  [`Semigroup`](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html) and [`SemigroupK`](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroupk.html).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do with `SemigroupK` which you can't do with `Semigroup` is to compose instances for [`Nested`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/155f7f534993c30d6e757de990330ac796dad5da/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Nested.scala):

```
implicit def catsDataSemigroupKForNested[F[_]: SemigroupK, G[_]]: SemigroupK[Nested[F, G, ?]]
```

If you try to write an equivalent for `Semigroup`, I think the closest you would get is

```
implicit def catsDataSemigroupForNested[F[_], G[_], A](implicit sg: Semigroup[F[G[A]]]): Semigroup[F[G[A]]] // or Semigroup[Nested[F, G, A]]
```

which is not very useful! From search, I can't see anything else which is implemented for `SemigroupK` and *can't* be done using `Semigroup`, but I might have missed something.

But the main point of `SemigroupK` is that once you have it, you can automatically get a `Semigroup` too, exactly like `NonEmptyList` does.

Comment: Ok, so I guess `Nested` and the `<+>` operator which has a slightly different semantic are so far the 2 reasons.
But when you say that once you get a `SemigroupK` you can have a `Semigroup`, I would rather say that once you have that `SemigroupK` you _must_ get a `Semigroup`, otherwise it wouldn't be much useful (so I wouldn't call that a feature).

Comment: No, you can use `SemigroupK` directly without getting a `Semigroup`: that's what `<+>` is for. (I personally would consider a mismatch between `<+>` and `|+|` like the one `Option` has to be a minor misfeature which is probably not worth getting rid of, not a reason to use `SemigroupK`; but I guess the instance for `Semigroup` was added before `SemigroupK` existed.)